# PyCharm scrolling down like SublimeText

Tags: scroll, pycharm, user-experience

I started using PyCharm again and I am missing this perfect scrolling from Sublime Text where you can scroll down so much that the last lines of code are in the middle (or even top) of the screen.
Is it somehow possible in PyCharm? I can only simulate it by adding many blank lines at the end of file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried this? It seems to allow what you are describing:

Settings -> Editor -> Virtual Space -> Show virtual space at file bottom

Comment: Thank you.  I overlooked this feature when searching in PyCharm since it's called *virtual space* instead of overscroll or *scroll_past_end* like Sublime.

Answer (score 1):

If you are finding it hard to find the 'Virtual Space' option to make it possible to scroll past the end, make sure to try typing it into the search box at the top of the settings window

Answer (score 0):

From the main menu on my mac:

PyCharm -> Editor -> General -> Virtual Space -> Show virtual space at file bottom

Or as suggested, just type Virtual space in the search box at the top of 
 the Preferences window.